How can a differentiable function not have a continous derivative
I understand mathematically that a function can be differentiable but its derivative might have discontinuities, it's not necessary that the derivative of a differentiable function be continuous.
What I can't wrap my mind around is why? Intuitively, let's say I have a function $f(x)$ which is differentiable everywhere on a closed interval $I$, and its derivative $f'(x)$ has a jump discontinuity somewhere in the interval. Then how would the function $f(x)$ be differentiable at the point where the derivative has a jump discontinuity? Shouldn't the two sides of the limit differ, making it not differentiable everywhere? I feel like if the derivative of a function is continuous except at a certain number of points, then the function itself should be differentiable everywhere except at those points, but this isn't necessarily true, and I would like some sort of intuitive explanation of why that is.

In fact, derivatives DON'T have jump discontinuities. See Deducing that $f'(x)$ cannot have jump discontinuity from a theorem AND Confused about jump discontinuities of derivatives AND Prove that if a function $f$ has a jump at an interior point of the interval $[a,b]$ then it cannot be the derivative of any function. See also the discussion and graphs in this MSE answer by Mark McClure.

By Darboux's theorem the derivative cannot have a jump discontinuity, so your intuition there is correct. I recommend seeing, for example, this to see what can happen

If the derivative $f'$ is defined everywhere, then $f'$ cannot have jumps.  But $f'$ can have a discontinuity that is not a jump.
You can try to find an example of this of the type: $f(x) = x^a\sin(1/x^b)$ and $f(0)=0$.
See also How to prove that derivatives have the Intermediate Value Property and How discontinuous can a derivative be?
